# Scrollable Error: "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded."

Tags: flutter

I get the following error for my code

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
The affected RenderFlex is:
  RenderFlex#35d16 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← ⋯, parentData:  (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: Size(360.0, 61.0), direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)
The creator information is set to:
  Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← ⋯
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#f779b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  needs compositing
  creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← _RawMouseRegion ← ⋯
  parentData:  (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=467.2)
  layer: OffsetLayer#5728c
  size: Size(360.0, 467.2)
See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():

RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is

in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a

flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining

space in the vertical direction.

These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child

cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible

children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size

themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and

then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum

constraints provided by the parent.

If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():

  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer

  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html

The affected RenderFlex is:

  RenderFlex#35d16 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← ⋯, parentData:  (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity), size: Size(360.0, 61.0), direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, verticalDirection: down)

The creator information is set to:

  Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ←

  _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ←

  Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ←

  CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← ⋯

The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#f779b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:

  needs compositing

  creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ←

    _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ←

    Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ←

    CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← _RawMouseRegion ← ⋯

  parentData:  (can use size)

  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, h=467.2)

  layer: OffsetLayer#5728c

  size: Size(360.0, 467.2)

See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/

If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:

  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md


The relevant error-causing widget was:

  Column

  /lib/screens/added_challenge_info.dart:54:34


When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

dart:sdk_internal 5348:11                                         throw_

packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 926:9                    

packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 928:14                   performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1779:7                 layout

packages/flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart 581:7  performLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1636:7                 [_layoutWithoutResize]

packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 881:17                 flushLayout

packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 462:19                drawFrame

packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 876:13                  drawFrame

packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 328:5                 [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]

packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1144:15               [_invokeFrameCallback]

packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1082:9                handleDrawFrame

packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 998:5                 [_handleDrawFrame]

dart:sdk_internal 186345:7                                        invoke

dart:sdk_internal 166271:15                                       invokeOnDrawFrame

dart:sdk_internal 183434:55                                       


The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#35d16 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:

  creator: Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ←

    _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ←

    Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#2e976] ← RepaintBoundary ←

    CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#46173] ← ⋯

  parentData:  (can use size)

  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)

  size: Size(360.0, 61.0)

  direction: vertical

  mainAxisAlignment: start

  mainAxisSize: max

  crossAxisAlignment: center

  verticalDirection: down

This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):

    child 1: RenderPadding#0a03f relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT

      child: RenderFlex#94b34 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT

        child 1: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#7d3ea relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT

          child: RenderMouseRegion#ff92e relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT

            child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#ca9a7 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT

        child 2: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#46b18 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT

          child: RenderMouseRegion#11cf7 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT

            child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#c1a5a relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT

    child 2: RenderStack#1baf2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

      child 1: RenderStack#6b82e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

        child 1: RenderRepaintBoundary#6d25a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

          child: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#cced9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

            child: RenderPointerListener#06fa5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

        child 2: RenderLimitedBox#fc4c2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

          child: RenderConstrainedBox#ec341 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

      child 2: RenderLimitedBox#ceb62 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

        child: RenderConstrainedBox#71b41 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Unexpected null value.

Another exception was thrown: Unexpected null value.

Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#1baf2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  needs compositing
  creator: Stack ← RankedList ← Expanded ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
  constraints: MISSING
  size: MISSING
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter
  textDirection: ltr
  fit: loose
Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).

Another exception was thrown: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.

Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#1baf2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  needs compositing
  creator: Stack ← RankedList ← Expanded ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
  constraints: MISSING
  size: MISSING
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter
  textDirection: ltr
  fit: loose
Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).

Assertion failed: /libmouse_tracker.dart:201:12
!_debugDuringDeviceUpdate
is not true

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///home/builder/hotbuilder/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:201:12

Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#1baf2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  needs compositing
  creator: Stack ← RankedList ← Expanded ← Column ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a73f2] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#2021f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight
  constraints: MISSING
  size: MISSING
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter
  textDirection: ltr
  fit: loose
Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).
```

My code is below:

I saw from similar posts that an approach I can take is to wrap the container within the scrollable with expanded so did so with _buildLeaderboard but that still didn't fix the bug... I'm wondering if it's because I'm adding RankedList to a Scrollable since it says on its pubdev
"RankedList uses scroll controller behind the scenes so you can't add your own scroll controller to the list as of now.".. If so how can I fix the issue?

Thank you as always!

```
class AddedChallengeInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Challenge challenge;

  const AddedChallengeInfo({required this.challenge});

  @override
  _AddedChallengeInfoState createState() => _AddedChallengeInfoState();
}

class _AddedChallengeInfoState extends State<AddedChallengeInfo> {
  int selectedId = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffFFAAA6),
        appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Color(0xff999999),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.trashAlt,
                  size: 20,
                  color: Color(0xff999999),
                ), // Icon
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, true);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20)
            ]),
        body: Stack(children: [
          ChallengeHeader(challenge: widget.challenge),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: 0.8,
              minChildSize: 0.8,
              maxChildSize: 1.0,
              builder: (BuildContext context, myScrollController) {
                return ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          controller: myScrollController,
                          child: Column(children: [
                            _buildScreenSelector(),
                            selectedId == 0 ? SizedBox() : _buildLeaderboard(),
                          ])),
                    ));
              })
        ]));
  }

  Widget _buildScreenSelector() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 30),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          _buildHeaderSelectorButton(0, "Intro"),
          _buildHeaderSelectorButton(1, "Leaderboard"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLeaderboard() {
    return Expanded(
        child: RankedList(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
            height: 500,
            color: index + 1 == 2 ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                '${index + 1}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
              ),
            ));
      },
      itemCount: 3,
      rank: 2,
      itemHeight: 56,
      topItem: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            '25',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomItem: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            '25',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      showBottom: false,
    ));
  }

  Widget _buildSelectorButton(int id, String t) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedId = id;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 56,
        height: 21,
        child: Text(
          '$t',
          style: TextStyle(color: id == selectedId ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: id == selectedId ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As said in the exception also, instead of using Expanded, maybe you should use `Flexible`.

Comment: @Pushpendra didn't work... dunno why

Comment: And what about mainAxisSize too in the column to min

Comment: @Pushpendra you cannot use mainaxissize on flexible and there is no column to add mainaxissize to

Comment: I meant, adding that in the column not in flexbile widget.